# Delete in admin override with confirmation.

Tags: python, django, admin

I had to override the delete method for admin like so :

```
def fully_delete_selected_photos(self, request, queryset):
    # Code to do my specific delete method.
fully_delete_selected_photos.short_description = "Delete Selected Photos"


class VehiclePhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('listing_id',)
    list_display = ('listing_id', 'disp_VehiclePhoto')

    actions = [fully_delete_selected_photos]

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(VehiclePhotoAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions
```

This works fine but I lost the confirmation of deletion. So when the user selects my "Delete Selected Photos" option it immediate just goes through with the delete. How can I get some kind of confirmation for the overridden deletion? I am confused about the redirections of views in admin.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you read this section of the docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages

Answer (score 0):

You can return HttpResponseRedirect  in fully_delete_selected_photos method, and make custom view , thats inherit template from admin, and takes queryset parameter, and  lists all selected photos. 
But if you want to simplify it, add some JavaScript to admin view.